# Matplotlib graph legend for multiple entries

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting several polygons in a plot:

```py
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

polygons.append(Polygon([(1,9), (4,9), (4,6), (1,6)]))
polygons.append(Polygon([(7,9), (10,9), (10,6), (7,6)]))
polygons.append(Polygon([(7,4), (10,4), (10,1), (7,1)]))
polygons.append(Polygon([(1,4), (4,4), (4,1), (1,1)]))
polygons.append(Polygon([(3,3), (3,7), (8,7), (8,3)]))

plt.figure()
for poly in polygons:
    plt.plot(*poly.exterior.xy)
plt.show()
```

The resulting plot correctly show my polygons, but I would like to know which one corresponds to which index on the plot (eg: the green polygon is the polygon at `polygons[2]`). Ideally I'd like a legend that associates the colour of the polygon with its index, but I can not figure out how to add such a legend in a loop like this. I have tried `plt.legend(polygons.index(poly))` but that did not work.

The amount of polygons is variable so strictly assigning colours is out of the question.

How can I add a legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have `shapely` installed but you can try something along these lines. You can use `label` parameter to mark the legends by tracking the polygon index using `enumerate`.

```
plt.figure()

for i, poly in enumerate(polygons):
    plt.plot(*poly.exterior.xy, label="Polygon %d"%i)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh it's the `label` keyword... Yep, that works perfectly, thank you!